# In Snowflake - converting a datetime from this format: 2022-10-17 17:18:07.000 to this format 17-Oct-2022 17:18:07

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datetime-format

using Snowflake sql, I need to convert datetime columns from this format: 2022-10-17 17:18:07.000 to this format 17-Oct-2022 17:18:07.  I'm trying to insert into Zoho and it does not like any other datetime formats I've tried.  The 17-Oct-2022 17:18:07 format was suggested.  Any thoughts?

I tried:

SELECT to_timestamp(LastLoginDate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as LASTLOGINDATE
FROM tablex;

but it tells me I have too many parameters for the to_timestamp function.  I'm new to Snowflake, but this has been harder to figure out than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to_char, not to_timestamp, as you are trying to change how the value is displayed rather than what the value actually is